# React Mui DateRangePicker include Calendar Icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I want to implement a [DateRangePicker from Material UI](https://mui.com/api/date-range-picker) with a calendar icon, e.g. it should look like that:
[image]

According to the Api documentation it should work with

```
components={{
  OpenPickerIcon: CalendarTodayIcon
}}
```

but it doesn't. See [codesandbock](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdaterangepicker-material-demo-forked-nhxhc?file=/demo.js).

I also tried it by adding an Icon manually to the TextField which shows an Icon but doesn't open the PopupMenu when clicking on the Icon.

```
InputProps={{
  endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="end">
      <IconButton>
        <CalendarTodayIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </InputAdornment>
  )
}}
```

Anyone an idea how to implement that? I am using mui 5.1.0 and mui/lab 5.0.0-alpha.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the Component from the library but you're right according to the documentation

```
components={{
  OpenPickerIcon: CalendarTodayIcon
}}
```

Should work but it doesn't.

In your workaround, you're not supplying anything on the `IconButton` onClick event handler so naturally, the icon does nothing when clicked.

What you need to do is focus on the input whenever the Icon is clicked. You can achieve that by using the `useRef` hook in your input and then calling the `current.focus()` method inside the onClick handler of the IconButton.

```
  const startInputRef = React.useRef();

<TextField
              inputRef={startInputRef}
              {...startProps}
              InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={() => {
                        startInputRef.current.focus();
                      }}
                    >
                      <CalendarTodayIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
            />
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdaterangepicker-material-demo-forked-bo3ri?file=/demo.js) for a working example.

I still think this is a hacky workaround though so I'd suggest opening an issue on the library's github repo to get instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you but I managed to do it properly using the `slotProps`:

```
<DateRangePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      InputProps: { endAdornment: <CalendarTodayRoundedIcon /> },
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example using also a `SingleInputDateRangeField`:

```html
<DateRangePicker
    label="Date Range"
    value={selectedFilters.dueDateRange}
    onChange={(value) => handleDateRangeChange('dueDateRange', value)}
    slots={{
        field: SingleInputDateRangeField,
    }}
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            size: 'small',
            InputProps: {
                startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <EventIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                ),
            },
        },
    }}
/>
```